# Updating a single pixel value in CIKernel for a custom CIFilter

Tags: ios, swift, opengl-es, core-image, cifilter

I'm working on creating a custom CIKernel that will embed a single bit value to pixel. The original idea was to pass through an array of bits and have them embedded into pixels on a bit basis but since array's are not supported I had to try a different approach.

The rough idea is that for the kernel I would give it a coordinate of (x,y) and a value of 1 or 0. The routine would only embed the value into the pixel (say by moving the r value up 1 value or down if 0) for the specific coordinate.

I've been trying to work on it in quartz composer and have come up with this

```
kernel vec4 adjustPixelValue(sampler image, float embeddedByte, vec2 coord)
{
    vec2 coord = samplerTransform(image, coord);
    vec2 curCor = destCoord();
    vec2 diff = curCor - coord; 
    float dist = length(diff);

    vec4 cur1 = sample(image, coord);
    cur1.r = cur1.r + embeddedByte;
    vec4 cur = sample(image, samplerCoord(image));

    return mix(cur1, cur, clamp(dist-1.0, 0.0, 1.0));
}
```

Which get the desired effect in quartz composer but not when I run the kernel in the app. To do that I'm using

```
    let xcoord : CGFloat = 400;
    let ycoord : CGFloat = 400;
    let dod  = image.extent;
    var args = [image as AnyObject];
    args.append(Int(1) as AnyObject);
    args.append(CIVector(CGPoint: CGPoint(x: xcoord, y: ycoord)));
    return kernel!.applyWithExtent(dod, roiCallback: {(n : Int32, rect: CGRect) -> CGRect in return rect; }, arguments: args)!;
```

I'm not sure what is the cause or if there is a better solution, ideally the end result would be that the filter could be used to embed a number of bytes into an image, using bit values.

Any help would be great!